# Replacement for "prev_ds" macros in Airflow

Tags: airflow

As prev_ds macro is deprecated, i am using `"{{ dag_run.get_previous_dagrun().execution_date | ds }}"`
However its failing for the first DAG run. is there any way to get the result like `prev_ds` macro

tried using the macro - `"{{ dag_run.get_previous_dagrun().execution_date | ds }}"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacement for prev\_execution\_date as it is deprecated in airflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77979686/replacement-for-prev-execution-date-as-it-is-deprecated-in-airflow-2)